# -[UIView setContentSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d3be60

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I'm following Apple's [Scroll View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH101-SW1). It seams very straightforward, but I'm getting this error:

`-[UIView setContentSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d3be60`
`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setContentSize:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d3be60'`

I followed the steps in *Creating Scroll Views in Interface Builder*. It's clear that `self.view` is of type `UIView`, when it should be `UIScrollView`. I control+dragged from the controller to the scroll view, as indicated in the tutorial and it seems that the scroll view is registered as a view in this controller, as the following screen shot shows:

[image]

I tried clicking that 'x' in View so Scroll View would be only view in the controller, but to no effect (as being grayed out would indicate).

What am I missing?

By the way, here's the code that crashes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Setup scroll size
    UIScrollView *view = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 960);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.. But why would apple do otherwise in the guide? Go figure..

Comment: What are you saying, that `view` is a conflicting name? I don't think so..

Comment: @MohitPopat, that is far away from any _not correct_ way, maybe odd, but saying _not correct_ is definitely a very strong false statement about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this, after creating a *brand new* `UIViewController`:

## before

the *Custom Class* is a basically an instance of the `UIView`.

[image: before]

## after

I have changed the *Custom Class* explicitly to `UIScrollView`, and that was pretty much the job, you needed to do achieving it.

[image: after]

---

from that point you can cast and use the `self.view` as `UIScrollView` inside the class because that it is a *pure* instance of `UIScrollView`.

---

---

## update for Attributes Inspector

basically that solution does not update the originally created `xib` file's `XML` tags, and it is still recognised as `UIView` only by the *Attributes Inspector*.

if that is a *brand new* and *empty* view you can drag'n'drop a new `UIScrollView` into your `xib` file, and can connect it to the *File's Owner*'s `view` properly to it, like e.g.:

[image: re-connent the view property]

the correct result:

[image: the scrollview is the new one]

the original view can be deleted after, because it is no longer connected to the *File's Owner*.

## advanced-mode

if you have a lot of sub-views already in your view, the copying-pasting way may not work for you with the above mentioned lighthearted solution about exchanging the views – you can establish a *full-contact* with the `XML` file – ***if you feel experienced and confident enough to edit that file manually!*** if you have any tiny doubt, do not touch or edit the `XML` file directly!

if yes, you need to update the main tags only from `view` to `scrollView`, like e.g.:

[image: view-tag] [image: scrollView-tag]

---

after any way of the changes the *Attribute Inspector* will treat the view as a *pure* `UIScrollView`.

Comment: Downside to this approach: the Attributes Inspector does not show properties for the scroll view.

Comment: @AndréFratelli, yes, that is true – I've updated my answer for solving that inconvenience as well.

Answer (score 2):

Casting operator you used in this statement: `UIScrollView *view = (UIScrollView*)self.view;` will not transform your `UIView` instance to `UIScrollView` instance.
Add a scroll view in .xib/.storyboard to your view controller's view and add an outlet to it.

Comment: I did had the UIScrollView. I followed what the tutorial says. If I understand correctly, you are saying that I can't replace the original view?

Comment: @AndréFratelli Exactly. Add a UIScrollView instance to a main view of UIViewController.